# Centrally Deploying a wireless SSID

Tags: windows, wifi, group-policy

So I want deploy a WPA2-Personal SSID that our managed clients will already have the network settings setup for(windows vista and windows 7 x64).  I also want to deploy the network configuration via gpo so I can avoid touching the hundrids of machines.  However I can't find how to make the gpo take the PSK.  I've read articles saying that GPOs can't do that but I havn't found any way to manually add the network config in via scirpt or anything like that.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an officially Microsoft-supported way to distribute a pre-shared key w/ group policy. Trying to do it with registry hacking, I suspect, is going to lead to misery. Perhaps you should think about 802.1x and give up on PSK.

Comment: Humm..  Okay I'll look into that again and what it'd take.  Thanks,